Main Page Blocked by robots.txt
I use this codes in robots.txt and today I see that google search console say my main page blocked by robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?route=checkout/
Disallow: /*?route=account/
Disallow: /*?route=extension/
Disallow: /*?route=affiliate/
Disallow: /*?route=product/search
Disallow: /*&limit
Disallow: /*?limit
Disallow: /*?sort
Disallow: /*&sort
Disallow: /*?order
Disallow: /*&order
Disallow: /*?price
Disallow: /*&price
Disallow: /*?mode
Disallow: /*&mode
Disallow: /*?cat
Disallow: /*&cat
Disallow: /*?dir
Disallow: /*&dir
Disallow: /*?color
Disallow: /*&color
Disallow: /*?minprice
Disallow: /*&minprice
Disallow: /*?maxprice
Disallow: /*&maxprice
Disallow: /*tag=
Disallow: /*&create=1
Disallow: /*?keyword
Disallow: /*?av

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

whats the problem? how can fix it?
My Main page of website Blocked By robots.txt and i dont know why
